# Basic principle about a benefit of XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, serialization

I am currently reading an WPF tutorial and i don't fully understand the following benefit being described. Can someone explain me in more detail what is being said?

**Benefit of XAML**

*Representation of any public .NET Framework class in XAML, if the class exposes a 
default constructor. This feature is possible because XAML is an XML-based 
serialization format for .NET Framework objects.*

Comment: Is the tutorial available online? It's unclear how this is a "benefit", if at all. Sounds like bad phrasing. Or do they mean benefit over something else?

Comment: Maybe you should provide a link to the tutorial (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is that you can create .NET object graphs in a declarative way (mainly for UIs) and you can extend it:

> Representation of any public .NET Framework class in XAML, if the
>   class exposes a default constructor

So it is easier to declare UIs (than from code), easier to separate the UI from business logic and easier to work together with other teams.

It is a much cleaner solution than creating UI elements from C# code for example.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in XAML and calls the default constructor

```
     <Frame Source="PageSearch.xaml" />
```

If you want to pass data to the page then you must do so in code behind.  In this case I am passing (GabeLib.DocFieldStringMV)df to the page.

```
     PageDocFieldDetailRWtextMV nextPage = new PageDocFieldDetailRWtextMV((GabeLib.DocFieldStringMV)df);
            SrchItemEditField.Content = nextPage;
```